# externalize namespace JAXB generated package-info.java

Tags: java, jaxb

How to externalize the namespace value in package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://loclahost:9093/Request", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

in the above code how should externalize the  "http://loclahost:9093/Request".

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Annotation attribute values have to be compile time constants so the best you can do is to declare a `public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://example.com"` in another class and then say `namespace = MyClass.NAMESPACE` in the annotation.  But you'd still have to re-compile `package-info.java` when `MyClass` changes.

Comment: I want to read the value like System.getProperty("nameSpace"); in MYClass

Comment: @premchanderjonnala - Did you see my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13013163/383861)?  Do you really need the namespace to be dynamic?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I need the namespace to be dynamic

Comment: @premchanderjonnala It's not possible, annotation attribute values _must_ be compile time constants.

Comment: Lan Roberts :-- Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The namespace specified on the the `@XmlSchema` annotation isn't meant to correlate to the physical location of the XML schema.  It is used to qualify the element, so that your `address` element is different from another organizations use of an `address` element.  This is similar to package names in Java.  As with package names, people generally use domain names for this purpose.  I can't think of a good reason to have the namespace look like:  `http://loclahost:9093/Request`.